# How to differentiate two iframes present on the same jsp

Tags: java, jsp, web-applications, iframe, liferay

I have two iframes added in a jsp page, with same name, display name and so on. I am having two different urls which has to be set as target urls in each of these iframes.How can I differentiate these two iframes and set the target urls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the id attribute which is standard for most html elements (iframe included)

Comment: yeah its true. In my present working project, iframe(Liferay portlets), gets added automatically based on number of urls present. So, the iframes will have same name, display name, etc.. So now am in a fix on how to set the urls

Comment: Have you tried passing an id=someId as parameter as it sais here: http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Iframe+Portlet#section-Iframe+Portlet-Controlling+the+attributes+of+the+iframe+window

Comment: Cool. Well this seems to get me back on track. Thanks Andrei.

Comment: Well this thing is not exactly solving the purpose since those two iframes are triggered and set at the same time. So even if I give some iframe atrib=some value, it would get set for both the iframes. I have to find a way to uniquely do this.

Comment: Can't you maybe place each iframe in a separate div, and each separate div would have a different id? And then when you wanna update a certain iframe, you first get the parent div, then get its child (the iframe) and then update that iframe?

Answer (score 0):

You *could* give them a different `id` so that you can grab them by JavaScript. But, actually, the `name` of the `<iframe>` is supposed to be **unique**. Fix that accordingly. This way you can distinguish them by their name in the `target`.

Comment: yeah its true. In my present working project, iframe(Liferay portlets), gets added automatically based on number of urls present. So, the iframes will have same name, display name, etc.. So now am in a fix on how to set the urls

Comment: the 'name' attribute on the iframe is deprecated, he should just replace it with id.

Comment: @Andrei: that applies only to XHTML, not HTML. Even in HTML5 it's not deprecated. Sending a simple JSP as XHTML makes no sense. XHTML is only to be used in server side XML view technologies which generate HTML. JSP isn't such a view technology. JSPX and Facelets are.